# Fill HTML table from JSON object using angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to get data from json object and using ng-repeat show that data inside of a HTML table.

I am getting data with $http and later using ng-repeat for writing the rows of table.

This is my json object:

```
{
  "tests": [
    {
      "date": "08/02/1999",
      "name": "Test 1",
      "test": "Raven"
    },
    {
      "date": "11/09/1998",
      "name": "Test 2",
      "test": "PCT+"
    },
    {
      "date": "13/01/2005",
      "name": "Test 3",
      "test": "PCT"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I am trying to get json into angular variable:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
testApp.controller('TestListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('GlobalData.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.tests = data;
    });
});
```

And this is my HTML for table:

```
<script src="batteriesScript.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng:repeat="t in tests">
        <tr>
            <td>{{t.date}}</td>
            <td>{{t.name}}</td>
            <td>{{t.test}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the index page where I have calls to different views depending on which link is clicked. Table content is in first view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Demo">
<head>
    <title>BatteryApp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/routes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="font-family: Arial">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="header">
                <h1>
                    Battery Application
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftMenu">
                <a href="#/home">Home</a>
                <a href="#/addBattery">Add new battery</a>
            </td>
            <td class="mainContent">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                <b>Battery</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Data is not shown on the page and I do not get any exception in browser console.

[image]

Second problem I have is that I do not see all files and folders from my solution in Chrome console:

[image]

I am missing Batteries folder where is the code I am using for my table and accessing to data.

[image]

So practically I am unable to debug it and try to find some errors.

Does anybody have idea how can I solve Chrome problem and does anybody spots potential errors in code for generating HTML table using angular.js?

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="results" width="360" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Date Created</th>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Tests</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr ng-repeat="t in tests">
            <td>{{t.date}}</td>
            <td>{{t.name}}</td>
            <td>{{t.test}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Change the location of the `ng-repeat`. The row should be repeating, not the table body, right?

As far as the missing folder is concerned, see if you have included the `batter.js` file in your `index.html`. Or share your `index.html` code

It looks like it should be `Batteries/batteriesScript.js` in the script tag

Comment: Yes you were right, place for ng-repeat was wrong, but still no data in the table :( @DustinToothless

Comment: It looks like it should be `Batteries/batteriesScript.js` in the script tag

Comment: That helped with seeing Batteries folder in console, now I can try to debug it and see if I even getting json data correctly :) @DustinToothless